# How to Javascript on Wordpress page to convert string to Page Title

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

Assume I have a manually coded menu of links which I want to include in the body of many Wordpress pages. Everything about the menu is the same from page to page, except part of the link text. The menu link text contains a string like "[variable]". So the html is structured like:

```
<li><strong><a href="#definition">What is [variable]?</a></strong></li>
```

I want to add some Javascript to this string such that it will be converted onload (or something) to the Wordpress Page Title.

How might I structure this Javascript?

Comment: Do you want to change the Page title by using javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You can use wordpress's in-built function 'get_the_title()' to display the title of the post/page.

```
<li><strong><a href="#definition">What is <?php echo get_the_title();?></a></strong></li>
```

Now if you want to use this in multiple places, you can use wordpress's another inbuilt function 'get_template_part()'.

```
<?php get_template_part('template-parts/custom'); ?>
```

This assumes that you have a folder named 'template-parts' in your theme folder with file 'custom.php' in it.

Add the above code in custom.php and then call it wherever you want.

Note: this is just one method to reuse code.